# -Unzip failed...Access is denied- error while adding Android SDK components to Eclipse

Tags: android

Eclipse (3.5) -->Window-->Android SDK and AVD Manager--><>
When Adding SDK Components, there is the following error message:

Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 7, revision 1
Installing Documentation for Android SDK, API 7, revision 1
Unzip failed: C:\Program Files\Android_SDK\temp\DocPackage.new01\navtree_data.js (Access is denied).

This is followed by another message: -Nothing is installed-
I use Windows 7 64-bit system.
Could anyone please help to get around this? Thank you in advance.
vmitsura

Answer (score 30):

The easy answer to this question is Right click eclipse.exe and select "Run as Administrator". Now it should all work as a charm.

Note that this only works if you originally did "Run as Administrator" when you first installed the Google plugins.  If not, they may be disabled when you Run as Administrator and then you may need to delete the plugins and start over doing this.  Otherwise, you'll keep having problems with permissions down the road.

Comment: When I do that my plug ins are disabled/missing. Anyone else?

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with versions of Windows since Vista. The "access is denied" message appears when you do not have write permissions to created files & directories in the Program Files directory (which is the case by default).

Comment: I have set write permissions for all involved files & directories, but still get this error. Any suggestinons?

Comment: Windows Vista onwards have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and tried to run Eclipse, with the 'Run as administrator' option, but to no avail. I ended up moving the Android SDK to D:/ from C:
I am able to proceed now.

Comment: This is a great solution. Don't need to move it off c:/ altogether though, just somewhere outside the **Program Files** folder.

Comment: @Gaur : Excellent solution, was very helpful for me .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way...
Go to Program(x86) -> Android -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> Security -> (In group or user names) choose "Users" click "Edit" then check the "Full Control", "Modify", and "Write"
Good luck my peers

Answer (score 0):

Right click the android folder on program files, and set Modify premission to Users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to run the Eclipse and SDK manager as administrator, without any luck.

For me, the trick was to temporarily disable my anti-virus (Avast in my case), and proceed to the installation with the SDK manager.

Answer (score -2):

Yes that is true and now working.

Please doing this 3 step all people:

1. have an us intenet ip
2. run the program ass adminstrator
3. change android  directory to d than current c 100% work dont worry

( if u have other prob conet me than facebook page facebook.com/milad.mosapoor)